# Passing structure through Pointer param in JNA(Found solution by myself)

Tags: jna

**Found solution**, leaving post, in case someone will find it useful.

Now it seems so oblivious... but when you pass the structure by its Pointer in some native function, it simply does not know that it need to reread itself from native memory.
Everything you need to do, in cases like mine, is to call structures method autoRead() after native method returns, and structure will reread itself from native memory.

Here is some example:

```
// Original C code
typedef struct _SomeStructure {
  int x, y;
} SomeStructure;

void DoSomesthing(BYTE* data, int param);   //returns lots of data types, 
                                            //including SomeStructure    

// Equivalent JNA mapping
class SomeStructure extends Structure { public int x, y; }
void DoSomesthing(Pointer data, int param);
...
SomeStructure st = new SomeStructure();
DoSomesthing(st.getPointer(), 100);
st.autoRead(); //structure will be filled
```

This trick will work only if you need to get some structure from native function.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

Currently I`m working on exstension of JNA, so it could use MSCAPI, and I faced a little problem.

MSCAPI functions designed in quite specific way, so the work completely different way with different params. In particularly

`BOOL WINAPI CryptGetProvParam(

  __in     HCRYPTPROV hProv,

  __in     DWORD dwParam,

  __out    BYTE *pbData,

  __inout  DWORD *pdwDataLen,

  __in     DWORD dwFlags

);`

function returns [PROV_ENUMALGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387440(v=vs.85).aspx) structure in pbData param, when PROV_ENUMALGS flag is set, but in other cases it could return handles, 0t-strings and lots of other stuff.
So I mapped it with:

`boolean CryptGetProvParam(

HCRYPTPROV hProv,

int dwParam,

Pointer pbData,

IntByReference pdwDataLen,

int dwFlags

);`

But, when I`m tried to call it with PROV_ENUMALGS.getPointer() (as pbData param) structure was not filling, so I ended up with having overloaded function with pdData type PROV_ENUMALGS.  It`s working, but feeling, that there is some better way to do it, then having overloaded function, does not leave me for a week...

So, guys, any suggestions?

PS Sorry for my bad English, and formatting skills.

Perhaps i wasn`t very clear first time, here is some more code:
        HCRYPTPROV hProv = JMSCAPIUtil.contextVerify(null, 420);

```
    PROV_ENUMALGS algs = new PROV_ENUMALGS();       

    if(Advapi32.INSTANCE.CryptGetProvParam(hProv,
            Advapi32.PP_ENUMALGS,
            algs,//.getPointer(),
            new IntByReference(algs.size()),
            Advapi32.CRYPT_FIRST)){
        System.out.println(algs.aiAlgid+"\t"+algs.dwBitLen+"\t"
                + new String(algs.szName,0,algs.dwNameLen.intValue()));
    }else{
        int err=Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();
        System.out.println(err);
    }       

    JMSCAPIUtil.contextRelease(hProv);
```

Here is result:

```
26154   256 GOST 28147
```

Obviously, it calls

```
boolean CryptGetProvParam(
        HCRYPTPROV hProv,           
        int dwParam,                
        PROV_ENUMALGS pbData,           
        IntByReference pdwDataLen,  
        int dwFlags                         
        );
```

mapping.

If `,//` deleted, it calls

```
boolean CryptGetProvParam(
        HCRYPTPROV hProv,           
        int dwParam,                
        Pointer pbData,                 
        IntByReference pdwDataLen,  
        int dwFlags                     
        );
```

mapping, and result will be:

```
0   0
```

Apparently, structure does not fills, when passed by pointer.

Comment: When you use `dwParam`  in `PP_ENUMALGS` mode, you can define `pbData` as `byte[]` array type. Define a variable with cast `PROV_ENUMALGS` onto preallocated memory using constructor `Structure(Pointer p)` i.e. `PROV_ENUMALGS prov = PROV_ENUMALGS(buffer)` where the buffer (a `Memory` or a `Pointer`) stores the output comes from `pbData`. An example on how to do this can be studied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949798/jna-event-log-reader

Comment: @ee. Still does not works. Found better, much simpler solution.

Comment: JNA writes a Structure's Java fields to native memory and populates them from native memory around native calls.  By default it does this automatically whenever it can recognize it's dealing with a Structure and the Structure's autoXXX property has not been turned off.  As you discovered, if you use a Pointer rather than a Structure (the latter is preferred), JNA has no idea that there exists a Structure that needs to by synched.