# How do I read Windows Event Log field names using JNA?

Tags: java, windows, jna

I am using JNA to read Windows event logs. I can get a fair amount of data out of each record but I can't quite get the field names.

To read logs I am doing

```
EventLogIterator iter = new EventLogIterator("Security");
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    EventLogRecord record = iter.next();
    System.out.println("Event ID: " + record.getEventId()
        + ", Event Type: " + record.getType()
        + ", Event Source: " + record.getSource());
    String strings[] = record.getStrings();
    for(String str : strings) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

I can get data like the id, type, and source easily. Then I can get the list of strings which may be for SubjectUserSid, SubjectUserName, etc.

I've been trying to get the data that I want with the field names. Is there an easy way to extract the field names/headers for each of the strings from record.getStrings()? I noticed there is a byte[] data variable in the record. I have tried to read this but I haven't been able to get any useful information from it. I know I can get the data length and offset for certain variables which I think I could extract the data that I want that way but I was wondering if that was correct or if there was an easier way.

Comment: Where's your assignment to `record`?  Is it of class `EventLogRecord`?

Comment: Edited to show the assignment to record. It is of the class EventLogRecord

Comment: I assume parsing output of powershell command line, executed from within Java via Runtime exec, is out of the scope of your request?   Sorry for the premature answer below, this looks a lot harder now that I understand what you want.

Comment: You can check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949798/jna-event-log-reader/10015479#10015479